# Tcm-ReIndex Tool is not showing progress even if number of items is very small

Tags: 2011

I am trying to run the Re-Index tool on one of CMS server. I have checked the check box for all publications. Number of messages it is showing is near about 3000 which in my perception is not very large number. But even after 15 minutes it is not showing any progress nor error. How long is it expected to show progress or is it some problem there?

[image]

Comment: Could it be that instead of not showing progress, your indexer service is stopped and not actually indexing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do following:

- Restart (regardless if they are in Start or Stop state) Search Host and Search Indexing Service (I would recommend restarting all Tridion services)
- Restart SDL Tridion Content Manager DCOM+ application

Now retry, it should resolve the issue

Answer (score 1):

After restarting the Search Indexer service the issue was resolved.